# Using VBA to fill a column based on the value in a separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run a macro between two worksheets where say column C in "Sheet 1" has a "Y", I need column AP in "Sheet 2" to return something along the lines of "covered" or "Y". Just something to indicate that a Y was there in Sheet 1. I am mainly running issues in actually connecting the two worksheets. This code below works fine if I am running it on columns within the same work sheet.

Code:

```
Private Sub Set_Border_Pattern(Requirements_Selector_Str As String)
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strRange As String
Dim strCellVal As String

If Len(Requirements_Selector_Str) > 2 Then
    strTemp = Mid(Requirements_Selector_Str, 4, 1)
Else
    strTemp = Requirements_Selector_Str
End If

With Worksheets("test")
    For i = 2 To REQUIREMENT_ROW_COUNT
        strRange = strTemp & i
        strCellVal = .Range(strRange).Value
        If strCellVal = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("NFR_List").Range(AP & i).Value = "Y"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: (1) You don't define `REQUIREMENT_ROW_COUNT`. (2) Should be `Range("AP" & i)`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you describe in a very simple way. I believe that if you understand it you will be able to modify it for your situation. If not, please feel free to ask questions.

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, i As Long
Set sh1 = Worksheets("test")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("NFR_List")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("C1")
Set r2 = sh2.Range("AP1")
i = 0
While r1.Offset(i, 0) <> ""
  If r1.Offset(i, 0) = "Y" Then r2.Offset(i, 0) = "Y"
  i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

I've assumed that Column C has no blank cells until the data is finished, but if this is not true, the code can be easily modified according to your needs.

Another approach would be to just use a formula for this (instead of VBA), such as `=IF(test!C1="Y", "Y","")` in `AP1` (if the "NFR_List" sheet) and then drag the formula down.  Or you could also put the formula in using VBA using code like, `r2.offset(i,0).formula = ...` . There are many ways.